# Sum of data from a text file

Tags: c++, file, text, while-loop, sum

I'm trying to add numbers from a text file which looks like something like this :

```
player1
132
41

player2
1150
323

player3
60
2
```

The output should give something like this:

```
41
41

323
364

2
366
```

Where the second number of the pair would display the sum of the previous numbers' first number of the pair. However, I end up getting this:

```
41
0

323
0

2
0
```

The data seems to be displaying correctly but I don't understand why the sum isn't even though it's in the same loop. Here's my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct player{
string name;
int nbmatches;
int nbvictories;
};

player data;
int main(){

ifstream readFile;
readFile.open("note.txt");
if (readFile.fail()){
    cout << "not found" << endl;
}
else
{
    readFile.clear();
    while (!ws(readFile).eof()){
        readFile >> data.name
            >> data.nbmatches
            >> data.nbvictories;

        int totalvictories = 0;
        data.nbvictories += totalvictories;
        cout << data.nbvictories << endl;
        cout << totalvictories << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: You are trying to do two things at once: read data from a file, and keep a running sum. Tackle them separately.

Comment: `data.nbvictories += totalvictories;` is this backwards?

Comment: "int totalVictories = 0" needs to be outside the loop

Comment: you are adding zero to `data.nbvictories`. This is because you are initializing `totalvictories` in every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

"totalvictories" must be declred outside of while

```
int totalvictories = 0;
while (!ws(readFile).eof()){
    readFile >> data.name
        >> data.nbmatches
        >> data.nbvictories;

    data.nbvictories += totalvictories;
    cout << data.nbvictories << endl;
    cout << totalvictories << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Not only does `totalvictories` need to be initialized outside the loop, the line in the middle should be reversed: `totalvictories += data.nbvictories`.

Comment: You could declare it as a static variable. Also, you can merge your two answers in one answer.

Comment: You're right. I am not good at editing text. Thank you your concerning.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in the following code is

```
int totalvictories = 0; //<- a non-static variable with local scope 
data.nbvictories += totalvictories; //<- you are adding zero every iteration
```

This `data.nbvictories` is modified twice every iteration. Once when you assign it with the number you get from the file and the second with `+=` which has not effect since `totalvictories = 0`. If `totalvictories` is supposed to store the total, then this variable should be modified not `data.nbvictories`, therefore, switch the statement to be `totalvictories += data.nbvictories;`

This is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct player{
string name;
int nbmatches;
int nbvictories;
};

player data;
int main(){

    ifstream readFile;
    readFile.open("note.txt");
    if (readFile.fail()){
        cout << "not found" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        readFile.clear();
        while ( readFile >> data.name >> data.nbmatches >> data.nbvictories   ){

            //int totalvictories = 0;
            static int totalvictories = 0;
            //data.nbvictories += totalvictories;
            totalvictories += data.nbvictories; 

            cout << data.nbvictories << endl;
            cout << totalvictories   << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

The result is

```
41
41

323
364

2
366
```

---

**Extra:** avoid using `system("pause");` and `eof()`.

Answer (score 0):

Move **int totalvictories = 0** before your while loop, you are resetting it to 0 every iteration.